# <fieldset> like effect without using <fieldset> tag and with pure HTML (no CSS)

Tags: html

I want to write text on border without using fieldset tag and with pure HTML. I have the attached code and I want to replace CSS with pure HTMl.

```css
/* Defining a custom border on all sides except the top side */

.custom-field {
  border: 4px solid;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 32px 2px;
  padding: 8px;
}


/* Defining the style of the heading/legend for custom fieldset */

.custom-field h1 {
  font: 16px normal;
  margin: -16px -8px 0;
}


/* Using float:left allows us to mimic the legend like fieldset. The float:right property can also be used to show the legend on right side */

.custom-field h1 span {
  float: left;
}


/* Creating the custom top border to make it look like fieldset defining small border before the legend. The width can be modified to change position of the legend */

.custom-field h1:before {
  border-top: 4px solid;
  content: ' ';
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 2px 0 -1px;
  width: 12px;
}


/* Defining a long border after the legend, using overflow hidden to actually hide the line behind the legend text. It can be removed for a different effect */

.custom-field h1:after {
  border-top: 4px solid;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  left: 2px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Original fieldset tag
        for comparison -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Fieldset 1 Legend
  </legend>
  Original Fieldset
</fieldset>

<!-- Custom fieldset which is created
        using custom CSS above -->
<div class="custom-field">
  <h1>
    <span>Custom created Fieldset</span>
  </h1>
  <div>
    <label for="shipping_name">Name:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_name" id="shipping_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="shipping_street">Street:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_street" id="shipping_street">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by pure html you mean without using css rules and thus no ::before and ::after pseudoelements? but yet inline style is allowed of course isnt it?

Comment: `:before` and `:after` is the **old syntax**. You should use `::before` and `::after` instead.

Comment: Your posted HTML's "Custom created fieldset" does exactly what you want - so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if pure HTML means inline style attributes, here you go, if it's a good idea is another question =):

```html
<!-- Original fieldset tag
        for comparison -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Fieldset 1 Legend
  </legend>
  Original Fieldset
</fieldset>

<div class="justaspacer" style="margin-bottom: 24px;"></div>

<!-- Custom fieldset which is created
        using custom CSS above -->
<div class="custom-field" style="border: 2px groove #c0c0c0; margin: 0 2px; padding: 0.625em 0.75em 0.625em 0.75em; position: relative;">
  <h1 style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1; padding: 0 2px; background: white; margin: 0; display: inline-block; transform: translateY(-50%); position: absolute; top: -2px;">
    <span>Custom Legend</span>
  </h1>
  <div>
    <label for="shipping_name">Name:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_name" id="shipping_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="shipping_street">Street:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="shipping_street" id="shipping_street">
  </div>
</div>
```